# How should I get Open Graph JSON object to pass in facepy class

Tags: django, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, fandjango

I am trying to configure Open Graph in my app such that, when ever a person click a "link" in it, the app should "post" it on his feeds/ timeline/ activity. (*`I created open graph actions for these features and successfully added meta tags in the page`*).

So, I am using `fandjango` and `facepy` to do this job.

This is how my code looks..

```
from facepy import GraphAPI

@csrf_exempt
@facebook_authorization_required(permissions=["publish_actions"])
def ViewPage (request):
    access_token = request.facebook.user.oauth_token
    profile_id = request.facebook.user.facebook_id
    path = "/%d/feed" %profile_id

    # How should I get the OpenGraph JSON obj
    og_data = ??
    graph = GraphAPI(access_token)
    graph.post(path, og_data)
    ...
    return render_to_response("view.html", context)
```

How should I get the open graph JSON obj to pass in the above `graph` object as parameter so as to post data in feeds/ timeline/ activity?

If this is not the way, how should I do it?

**Edit 1:**

when I tried

```
graph = GraphAPI(request.facebook.user.oauth_token)
graph.post("me/namespace:action")

It showed me `OAuthError` 
Error Loc: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\facepy\graph_api.py in _parse, line 274


graph = GraphAPI(request.facebook.user.oauth_token)
graph.post("me/namespace:action", "object type")

It showed me `TypeError`
loc: same as previous
```

**Edit 2:**

Instead to using `request.facebook.user.oauth_token`, I directly used my [`access token`](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/) and the code worked..

```
graph = GraphAPI (my-hard-coded-access-token)
graph.post("me/feed", message = "working!")
```

However, when I tried

```
graph.post("me/news.reads", article="working")

It showed me error.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I created open graph actions

You shouldn't be using `me/feed` then

The OpenGraph calls are as follows

```
me/[app_namespace]:[action_type]?[object_type]=[OBJECT_URL]
```

So, to achieve the same just set the path to `me/[app_namespace]:[action_type]`

```
graph.post(
        path = 'me/[app_namespace]:[action_type]',
        [object_type] = '[OBJECT_URL]'
)
```

`og_data` is not a parameter in the call. So if your `object_type` is `recipe` then it would be

```
graph.post(path, recipe)
```

If you want to continue to use `me/feed` then it should be

```
graph.post(path, link)
```

as described at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts

---

You cannot do customs read actions like that, the proper call should be

```
graph.post(
    path = 'me/news.reads',
    article = 'http://yourobjecturl/article.html'
)
```

Please read the documentation http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/#read

Comment: I tried `graph.post("me/namespace:action", "object_type")` now its showing my `OAuthError`

Comment: @Surya what's your namespace, what's your action, what's your object_type and what's the OAuth Error

Comment: please take a look at the question

Comment: @Surya please read the documentation, http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/#read

Comment: can you tell me how to get og article object url in python.. that's what I am actually searching for from the beginning.

Comment: @Surya you have it :S `I created open graph actions for these features and successfully added meta tags in the page` The page is your object url.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an `OAuthError` because you're initializing the Graph API client with an instance of a class instead of a string.

Try this:

```
graph = GraphAPI(request.facebook.user.oauth_token.token)
```

Alternatively, you could use the `graph` propery of the Fandjango's `User` model to get a preinitialized instance of the Graph API client:

```
request.facebook.user.graph
```